# Where to install Build Cassandra is better on Mac

Tags: macos, cassandra, sudo

I have built Cassandra through Mac command manually.
The first time I have installed it under ~/Download folder and it builds fast, but at that time I didn't find /var/lib/cassandra so I removed cassandra from ~/Download file.

Then I have installed it under /, this time lots of operations needed "sudo" and it became slower.

So I am wondering where to install Cassandra is better? Since later I am going to pull large amount of data into Cassandra but I also hope it will influence my machine performance at the lowest level.

Answer (score 0):

Install Cassandra in a location where you can provision full access to it. The problem you faced was due to the fact that you left the directories of data and commitlogs to defaults. Change those in the cassandra.yaml file and start Cassandra.